# Auto Deployment of Ear file in Jboss server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have 10 instance of production boxes, I am planning to write an automated script which will deploy the application to all instances, I am planning to write a java based program as a wrapper for shell scripting.

Could you please let know whether we have any java based program to automatic deployment to Jboss server.

I know about the redhat cli, but does not look like it is available in my installation.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Is there a reason you included the Chef tag? Chef is not Java-based so unless you are also considering using Chef for this task (which would be fine) then I'm not sure it applies.

Comment: Do you using Jenkins?

Comment: Which version of JBoss ?